# Mi source muestra una multiplicación extra no esperada

Tags: c++

con unos amigos estábamos compitiendo para ver quién terminaba primero un programa para multiplicar todas las tablas de multiplicar del 1 al 10 (un poco extraño pero no teníamos otra idea), y yo hice lo propio en C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int v1 = 1, v2 = 1, limit = 10;
  for (; v1 <= (limit + 1); v1++) {
    if (v1 > limit) {
      v1 = 1;
      v2++;
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
    else if (v2 > limit) return 0;
    std::cout << v2 << "x" << v1 << " = " << int(v1 * v2) << "\n";
  }
}
```

Pero al compilar me doy cuenta que muestra una multiplicación extra.

[image: Resultado]

Supongo que el for loop es el problema, pero no sé qué tipo de solución tiene, por mi lo reescribiría pero quiero al menos encontrar el problema y que no me suceda lo mismo despues.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elimina el 'else' de

```
else if (v2 > limit)
```

Debería ser

```
if (v2 > limit)
```

Para que así verifique el valor de v2 > 10 aun cuando v1 se reinicie a 1. Actualmente solo hace una de las dos cosas.

Es más, nunca v2 va a ser mayor que limit a menos que entre al if inicial (donde v2 es aumentado) por lo que una mejor solución sería solo verificarlo dentro de ese if:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int v1 = 1, v2 = 1, limit = 10;
  for (; v1 <= (limit + 1); v1++) {
    if (v1 > limit) {
      v1 = 1;
      v2++;
      std::cout << "\n";
      if (v2 > limit) return 0;
    }
  
    std::cout << v2 << "x" << v1 << " = " << int(v1 * v2) << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha funcionado excelente, evidentemente no me había percatado de eso jajaja. Gracias por la solución.

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar liarse con límites, lo más fácil es usar el `for` de rango:

```
int numeros[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for (const auto &a : numeros)
{
    for (const auto &b : numeros)
        std::cout << a << 'x' << b << " = " << a * b << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZUxLDoIwEF13TjHRRMCMCf4V0Iuoi1LQkEBLSpuYEM5ewc9CXcybvK@o65koubw5Ny6kKG2WY1KoxuicV0eAQhqseCH9AFpgA5O2yrVqTpd2Tgta0orWtKEt7WhP87CLAdhVafSFko1Bbo3CCcfo0wuA9UP/kfQrwlhjsigSyhpMEuQDeHdveOkAIzz093SmL8U7Sy@Gn95b7IDp3FgtMYyhc@4B)</kbd>. Si tienes alergia a escribir números, puedes pedirle al compilador que los escriba por ti:

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

for (const auto &a : v)
{
    for (const auto &b : v)
        std::cout << a << 'x' << b << " = " << a + b << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RCoMwDEWf7VeEDaayTdyrOr9kL7V2UtBUaloGw2937RS2sYfchHtuQsQ4nkXPsVuWvULR21ZCpfRERvKhZh8P7SCNEt@Wk4K0qRlTSDBwhUnKniyaqC2KlVWe1OCSS56WG1CaeOKyRnYhfwKXSWzDcPERFt21gURonAi4JQ0HDgW4lEX@8D9sNhitt4W2BFUFPEj8iENrguzg6utNjqsT3zD2L/3ubebs/zCSrEHISzYvyws)</kbd>.

Comment: El problema es que exactamente era lo que buscaba evitar, una lista super larga de int's en un array/vector, de todas formas es una buena solución. Gracias.

Comment: _Si tienes alergia a escribir números, puedes pedirle al compilador que los escriba por ti._ Gracias por la otra solución xD